# How to unload a kernel module which is in use?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, sd-card, card-reader

I'm following this tutorial to get my card reader working: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=636867

However I'm unable unload my sdhci module:

```
sudo modprobe -rv sdhci mmc_core mmc_block
modprobe: FATAL: Module sdhci is in use.
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: By what other modules is sdhci used?

Comment: That's what I don't know how to find out

Comment: `lsmod | grep sdhci`

Comment: unloading sdhci_pci fixed it. Thanks! Wanna write that into an answer?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

First, find out, which other modules use the module `sdhci`:

```
lsmod | grep sdhci
```

You will get a list like this:

```
module size used_by
```

Try unloading these modules (used_by) before or together with the module you want to unload:

```
sudo modprobe -r <module found from lsmod> <module you want to remove>
```

If you want to prevent the module from loading on the next boot, add it to the blacklist:

```
echo -e "sdhci\n" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Comment: I tried this but didn't have any luck: http://askubuntu.com/questions/724052/unload-saa7164-module-for-hauppauge-2250-and-stop-tvheadend-to-suspend-ubuntu-1

Comment: What if I get "used by 1" but it does not says which one?

Comment: @AlejoDev the same for me. I get 'used by' value just 3.

Comment: A line `sdhci` in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` will not work. The line should be `blacklist sdhci` in `etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

Answer (score 5):

Another place to look at is **"lsof"** apart from unloading the dependent modules.

> **# lsof | grep < relevant str to module >**

This should list the files that are opened via the module. Try killing those processes that opened the files and check the module reference count is getting reduced through the **"lsmod"** command.

Comment: Great info! I had Nvidia drivers failing to run CUDA programs and typically `sudo modprobe -r nvidia_uvm && sudo modprobe nvidia_uvm` is the correct solution but this time got `FATAL: Module nvidia_uvm is in use` even though `lsmod` didn't list any users. However, `sudo lsof | grep uvm` did show that I had `nvtop` running which had file `/dev/nvidia-uvm` open which was the cause. After closing `nvtop` and doing the modprobe commands, the CUDA programs started to work again without a reboot.